# 2D Plot with labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Can you give me a hint on how could I draw such a plot? Literally I have no clue about how should I start.

I could draw two straight lines but my problem comes up when it comes to bending them. Not to mention the gap with the labels :(

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      %grid = major,   
      axis x line=left,
      axis y line=left,
      xlabel={Amount of data},
      ylabel={Performance}
   ]

    \addplot+[color=black,mark=none,samples=200,domain=0:10,smooth,thick] {*sqrt(1*x)} node[below,pos=1,color=black] {};

    \addplot+[color=blue,mark=none,samples=200,domain=0:10,smooth,thick] {2/8*sqrt(3*x)} node[below,pos=1,color=black] {};



    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could start with a minimal working example based on the examples in the pgfplots manual.

Comment: I am working on it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
%\pgfplotsset{}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\begin{axis}[ticks=none,ymax=2.3,
  %grid = major,   
  axis x line=left,
  axis y line=left,
  xlabel={Amount of data},
  ylabel={Performance}
]

\addplot[color=red,mark=none,samples=200,domain=0:10,smooth,thick] {tanh(x)}
node[above left,pos=1] {Older algorithms};

\addplot[color=blue,mark=none,samples=200,domain=1:10,smooth,thick]
{1/3*sqrt(3*x-3)} node[above left,pos=0.8] {Deep learning};

\draw[dashed,gray] (6,0) -- (6,{1/3*sqrt(3*6-3)}) node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt] (n1){};  
\draw[dashed,gray] (9,0) -- (9,{1/3*sqrt(3*9-3)}) node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt] (n2){};  
\end{axis}
\draw[gray] (n1) -- ([xshift=1cm]current axis.east|-n1) node[right]{blah};
\draw[gray] (n2) -- ([xshift=1cm]current axis.east|-n2) node[right]{blah blah};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where were you? I missed you, super genius! Thank you so much. Hat off!

Comment: +1: Impressively little code needed!